# Showing image caption only if caption exists - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, caption

I found a really helpful discussion here that outlines how to display the image caption, alt, title, etc. I've tested this function, and it works well, but for the images that don't have captions, the div for the caption still displays. How would I go about making this function display nothing, if there's no caption available?

```
function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
  global $post;

  $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id);

  $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'include'  => $thumb_id
); 

   $thumbnail_image = get_posts($args);

   if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
     //show thumbnail title
     echo $thumbnail_image[0]->post_title; 

     //Uncomment to show the thumbnail caption
     //echo $thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt; 

     //Uncomment to show the thumbnail description
     //echo $thumbnail_image[0]->post_content; 

     //Uncomment to show the thumbnail alt field
     //$alt = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
     //if(count($alt)) echo $alt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt != '')
{ 
    echo $thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt; 
}
```